# Error in configuring hibernate 5.0.1 and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have problem configuring the hibernate 5.0.1 with MySQL, I saw some questions here stating there is a bug in the version 4, I am not sure weather this is the same bug or I am doing something wrong.

Here is my configuration file
hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration
        xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping resource="org.cypher.dto.UserDetails"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and here is my sessionfactory code

```
SessionFactory sessionfactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(user);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Here is the error log.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 12 and column 63 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'.
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:245)
    at org.cypher.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:15)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you use hibernate.cfg.xml and not only persistence.xml? You use Hibernate's propriety API?

Comment: @MikeArgyriou yes i use hibernate API

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So here is the solution.

Replace

```
<hibernate-configuration
        xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

with

```
<hibernate-configuration>
```

and add below code at the top of the file.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Also in config file replace `<mapping resource=...>` to `<mapping class=...>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the following at the beginning of the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but it gives error on my hibernate-configuration declaration stating `"xmlns" must be declared for element type "hibernate-configuration".`

Comment: Try to replace the tag <hibernate-configuration ...> with the following: <hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration">

Comment: tried same, still no luck, same error, Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type "hibernate-configuration".

Comment: The error "Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'." means that the element hibernate-configuration cannot be found in http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd. So it seems that sth is wrong with the DTD.

Comment: Ok here is something i got, this is my final code
`<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 
 
<hibernate-configuration>`
now i get 
`Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.boot.MappingNotFoundException: Mapping (RESOURCE) not found `

Comment: I think that <mapping resource="org.cypher.dto.UserDetails"/> should point to the XML that has the entity's mappings and not to the entity. You should replace the attribute resource to class for your case. See also this link: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/ch01.html

Comment: If it worked then please accept my answer as correct.