# Hibernate ConfigurationException

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, exception, hibernate-mapping

I'm using Hibernate 5.1.0.Final and PostgreSQL 9.5; All jars are added to lib properly; Can someone please point out what is the actual problem here ?

[image: Exception details]

[image: TestHibernate class]

[image: hibernate config file]

Comment: FYI, The line throwing exception in TestHibernate is marked in blue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in configuring hibernate 5.0.1 and MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499073/error-in-configuring-hibernate-5-0-1-and-mysql)

Comment: didn't work in my case though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is the solution. mapping class will always be the class where you are creating all the attributes for the objects(the class containing details and getters,setters), not the one where you're using hibernate API to save objects to database.

```
<mapping class="org.hibernate.sample.UserDetails"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since hibernate 4.x buildsessionfactory() has been  deprecated. You need to fetch a session like below :

```
Configuration config = new Configuration()
          .configure();

ServiceRegistry serviceRegistery = new     StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();

SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistery);

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Comment: Same error in: Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();

Comment: `buildSessionFactory()` is not deprecated in Hibernate 5. And, sorry, your configuration approach will not work for Hibernate 5. Please, [check it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32711654/3405171)

Answer (score 0):

A problem, obviously, with `hibernate.cfg.xml` parsing. Try to use this template

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        ...   

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

And you need to close a session.