# Hibernate Java 9 Configuration File Error

Tags: hibernate, java-9

I recently migrated to Java 9 and find the following error.

Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null

The content of my configuration file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.databasename">ActiveDirectory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.integratedsecurity">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">1000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">1000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The exception is throw when I run the .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").
Do you have any idea of how should I face it?

Comment: Please update the question with the complete stack trace. Also, did you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499073/error-in-configuring-hibernate-5-0-1-and-mysql) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499073/error-in-configuring-hibernate-5-0-1-and-mysql)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

This happens because of Java 9.

Java 9 has deprecated java.xml.bind module and has removed it from the default classpath. That's why we get the class not found exception. The javax.xml.bind package is now a sub package of Module java.xml.bind.

So we simply have to add that module to the runtime configuration.

Solution:

Right-click your Java file, for example: CreateStudentDemo.java

Select Run As > Run Configurations ...

In the center panel, click the tab Arguments

In the section for VM Arguments, enter: --add-modules java.xml.bind

Click Run

Your application will run successfully.

---

Let me know your results.

:-)

---

[image]Modules are a new feature of Java 9. You can get details on Java 9 
modules here: https://blogs.oracle.com/java/modular-development

Comment: The right thing is to move to the standalone version, otherwise the project will need to be changed again when the java.xml.bind module is dropped from the JDK. All the details are in JEP 320 (http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320).

Comment: yes correct we can also this thing.Just got windows->preference->java->installJRE--> select jdk versio-> add VM Argument